# SQL SELECT from 2 tables with continuing data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in an SQL database, apart from the id they do not contain any duplicates and are just a continuation of each other...

```
table1

id  | item          | price
---------------------------
232 | Green apple   | 38
12  | Red Grape     | 2
3   | Yellow Banana | 38
5   | Yellow Mango  | 2

table2

id  | item          | price
---------------------------
33  | Blue Pear     | 34
1   | Purple Grape  | 23
72  | Orange Orange | 8
```

I am searching for items like this..

```
    SELECT
        item, price
        MATCH (item) AGAINST ('Grape') AS matchscore,
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        MATCH (item) AGAINST ('Grape')
    ORDER
        BY matchscore DESC
```

How can I add the `table2` items into the search? I have look at `UNION` but I do not think that is what I need here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a union here:

```sql
SELECT item, price, MATCH (item) AGAINST ('Grape') AS matchscore,
FROM table1
WHERE MATCH (item) AGAINST ('Grape')
UNION ALL
SELECT item, price, MATCH (item) AGAINST ('Grape')
FROM table2
WHERE MATCH (item) AGAINST ('Grape')
ORDER BY matchscore DESC;
```